# Values from private fields isn't displayed

Tags: php, forms, checkbox, private-members

I'm using private fields for the name attributes in forms instead of hard coding the values. However, by some reason the values isn't fetched from the private fields and put into the name attributes, and I just can't figure out why.

```
<?php

namespace View;

class UserView {

    private $checkBox = "check[]";
    private $submitRemove = "submitRemove";

    public function ShowUsers() {

        $userNameArray = array("foo", "bar", "hallo", "world");

        $userIdArray = array(1, 2, 3);

        $users = "";
        $nrOfUsers = count($userNameArray);

        // Name attribute of input fields created is left blank
        for ($i = 0; $i < $nrOfUsers; $i++) {
            $users .= "<label for='$userIdArray[$i]'>
                        $userNameArray[$i]
                        <input type='checkbox' name='$this->checkBox' value='$userIdArray[$i]' /><br/>
                        </label>";
        }

        $userList = "<div class='userList'>
                    <form id='form3' method='post' action=''>
                        <fieldset>
                            <p>Existing users</p>
                            $users
                            <input type='submit' id='$this->submitRemove' name='$this->submitRemove' Value='Ta bort' />    // name attribute is left blank
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                    </div>";

        return $userList;
     }
```

Comment: Testing your code with `$x=new UserView(); echo $x->ShowUsers();` outputs `<input type='submit' id='submitRemove' name='submitRemove' Value='Ta bort' />`.

Answer (score 1):

For "complex elements", such as arrays or attributes of an object, you can't call them just like a variable in a double-quoted string.

You have to escape them with braces:

```
<?php echo "This is a complex attribute: {$this->checkBox}"; ?>
```

or you can remove them from the quoted string:

```
<?php echo "This is a complex attribute: " . $this->checkBox; ?>
```

BTW, double quoted strings aren't recommended due to performance issues. Using simple quoted strings is better, it avoid to PHP to "read" the string to verify if there's a variable to display.

BTW2, to make your code more readable, a convention in PHP says that private attributes have to start by an underscore. You should rename `$checkBox` and `$submitRemove` to `$_checkBox` and `$_submitrRemove`.

BTW3, if those 2 variables aren't intented to change, you should consider to declare them as static variables. It'll prevent to have multiple copies of those variables inside each of instatiated objects.

Comment: Accessing a simple object property actually works in double quotes.

Comment: The [PSR-2](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md) standards say that there should be no underscores for private/protected members. Although it should be noted that this is a suggestion not a rule. The only rule for coding standards is consistency.

Comment: @WolfgangStengel yup that worked , using curly braces is just a best practice, i guess.

Comment: @WolfgangStengel: Thanks for information, is this a new functionnality since PHP 5.3?
Pinetree: Thanks for link. Seems lot of PHP conventions have changed since I stopped using PHP every day few months ago.

Comment: @Kyriog: Not sure, but I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the posted code. I think you are overwriting `$submitRemove` somewhere in another method.